# Inputs field highlight green when error is corrected with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form and when the input fields are empty by the time a print button is clicked to print should return false and highlight fields to red. At the same time when an input field has then a value, the field should highlight green, but this isn't working like it should. If one field has a value and the others not; at time the button is clicked to print, the field with value should highlight green and the others without value red.

Javascript

```
if (err !== 0){
$("#one, #two, #three, #four").effect("highlight", {color:"red"},
3000);
    $.notify("All fields with * must be filled", {
        position: 'bottom right',
        autoHide: true,
        autoHideDelay: 5000
    });
return false;
}
else {
  if ($("#one") !== "" && $("#two, #three, #four") == ""){
    $("#one").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
    return false;
}
if ($("#two") !== "" && $("#one, #three, #four") == ""){
    $("#two").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
    return false;
}
if ($("#three") !== "" && $("#one, #two, #four") == ""){
    $("#three").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
    return false;
}
if ($("#four") !== "" && $("#one, #three, #two") == ""){
    $("#four").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
    return false;
}
var print = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML code?

Comment: Hi Can you please create a fiddle for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/g0rbe0ox/), I'm not using your exact code, but it's the idea behind it.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
      $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
  });
});

$("input").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid green");
  }
})
```

```css
.form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
label {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
input,
select {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">

  <label for="txtName">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtName" />

  <label for="txtSurname">Surname</label>
  <input type="text" id="txtSurname" />

  <label for="txtSex">Sex</label>
  <select id="txtSex">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <button>
    Print!
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#print').click(function(){
      var err = 0;
      if ($("#one").val() == ""){
          $("#one").effect("highlight", {color:"red"}, 3000);
              err++;
      } else {
          $("#one").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
      }

      if ($("#two").val() == ""){
          $("#two").effect("highlight", {color:"red"}, 3000);
              err++;
      } else {
          $("#two").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
      }

      if ($("#three").val() == ""){
          $("#three").effect("highlight", {color:"red"}, 3000);
              err++;
      } else {
          $("#three").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
      }
      if ($("#four").val() == ""){
          $("#four").effect("highlight", {color:"red"}, 3000);
              err++;
      } else {
          $("#four").effect("highlight", {color:"green"}, 3000);
      }


      if (err !== 0){

          $.notify("All fields with * must be filled", {
              position: 'bottom right',
              autoHide: true,
              autoHideDelay: 5000
          });
      return false;
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $('.inputs').change(function () {    
        $('.inputs').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {    
                $(this).attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:red 1px solid;");    
            } else {    
                $(this).attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:green 1px solid;");    
            }    
       });    
    });    
});
```

Add class `inputs` to each input element to make the change as wanted